# What is the correct way to apply filter to a image

Tags: image-processing, imagefilter

I was wondering what the correct way would be to apply filter to a image. The image processing textbook that I am reading only talks about the mathematical and theoretical aspect of filters but doesn't talk much the programming part of it !

I came up with this pseudo code could some one tell me if it is correct cause I applied the sobel edge filter to a image and I am not satisfied with the output. I think it detected many unnecessary points as edges and missed out on several points along the edge.

[image: Input image]

[image: Output image]

```
int filter[][] = {{0d,-1d,0d},{-1d,8d,-1d},{0d,-1d,0d}};// I dont exactly remember the       //sobel filter
int total = 0;
for(int i = 2;i<image.getWidth()-2;i++)
    for(int j = 2;j<image.getHeight()-2;j++)
    {
        total = 0;

        for(int k = 0;k<3;k++)
            for(int l = 0;l<3;l++)
            {
                total += intensity(image.getRGB(i,j)) * filter[i+k][j+l];
            }

        if(total >= threshold){
        image.setRGB(i,j,WHITE);
    }
}

int intensity(int color)
{
    return (((color >> 16) & 0xFF) + ((color >> 8) & 0xFF) + color)/3;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't look quiet right to me. In order to apply the filter to the image you must apply the discrete time convolution algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution.

When you do convolution you want to slide the 3x3 filter over the image, moving it one pixel at a time. At each step you multiply the value of the filter 'pixel' by the corresponding value of the image pixel which is under that particular filter 'pixel' (the 9 pixels under the filter are all affected). The values that result should be added up onto a new resulting image as you go.

Thresholding is optional...

The following is your code modified with some notes:

```
int filter[][] = {{0d,-1d,0d},{-1d,8d,-1d},{0d,-1d,0d}};

//create a new array for the result image on the heap
int newImage[][][3] = ...

//initialize every element in the newImage to 0
for(int i = 0;i<image.getWidth()-1;i++)
    for(int j = 0;j<image.getHeight()-1;j++)
        for (int k = 0; k<3; k++)
        {
            newImage[i][j][k] = 0;
        }    

//Convolve the filter and the image
for(int i = 1;i<image.getWidth()-2;i++)
    for(int j = 1;j<image.getHeight()-2;j++)
    {
        for(int k = -1;k<2;k++)
            for(int l = -1;l<2;l++)
            {
                newImage[i+k][j+l][1] += getRed(image.getRGB(i+k ,j+l)) * filter[k+1][l+1];
                newImage[i+k][j+l][2] += getGreen(image.getRGB(i+k ,j+l)) * filter[k+1][l+1];
                newImage[i+k][j+l][3] += getBlue(image.getRGB(i+k ,j+l)) * filter[k+1][l+1];
            }
    }

int getRed(int color)
{
    ... 
}

int getBlue(int color)
{
    ...
}

int getGreen(int color)
{
    ...
}
```

Please note that the code above does not handle the edges of the image exactly right. If you wanted to make it absolutely perfect you'd start by sliding the filter mostly off screen (so the first position would apply the lower right corner of the filter to the image 0,0 pixel of the image. Doing this is really a pain though, so usually its easier just to ignore the 2 pixel border around the edges.

Once you've got that working you can experiment by sliding the Sobel filter in the horizontal and then the vertical directions. You will notice that the filter acts most strongly on lines which are perpendicular to the direction of travel (to the filter). So for the best results apply the filter in the horizontal and then the vertical direction (using the same newImage). That way you will detect vertical as well as horizontal lines equally well. :)

Comment: "At each step you multiply the value of the filter 'pixel' by the corresponding value of the image pixel which is under that particular filter 'pixel' (the 9 pixels under the filter are all affected)" I found this statement in a lot of material on convolution. I previously asked a question about this in SO and I find this to be a bit ambiguous, do we need to multiply the pixel value by the filter or take the intensity of the pixel color and then multiply the filter like in my code. if u have a non balanced filter I found that it leads to bleeding effect like the greens would be effecting red's

Comment: If you wish to apply the filter directly to the color image I think the way to do it is to apply it on each color channel independently (the values used being the value of each corresponding pixel color). You then reconstitute a new image given the new R G and B image components. I guess the problem with using the grayscale version of the image is that pixels of different colors may have similar brightness...

Comment: I think that lennon310 version of convolution may be equivalent (was thinking about this yesterday) except I would apply the result to a new image not overwrite the original image. The thing he said about the filters is also true. Id have to play with it myself and see, been a little while.

Comment: what about the case where I have like the following  values of green in the 9 locations {0,255,0},{255,2,255},{0,255,0} (let the image be a 3 X 3 square and the value of green at the 9 locations is given as shown) applying the filter centering at the pixel whose green is 2 that is the center I get the value of green as -255*4 + 2 how should I deal with it ? A) its negative B) Its greater than 255 should I only consider the lower order bits or higher order bits ?

Comment: Try truncating the values that are less than 0 to 0 and ones that are greater than 255 to 255. You can also take a look at the following http://lodev.org/cgtutor/filtering.html.

Comment: Thanks man, But hey the pixels are barely visible is there way I could increase the intensity after convolution ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44005/discussion-between-ron-and-aditya)

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

(1) The [sober operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) includes x-direction and y-direction, they are 
`int filter[][] = {{1d,0d,-1d},{2d,0d,-2d},{1d,0d,-1d}};` and

```
int filter[][] = {{1d,2d,1d},{0d,0d,0d},{-1d,-2d,-1d}};
```

(2) The convolution part:

```
total += intensity(image.getRGB(i+k,j+l)) * filter[k][l];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some serious undefined behavior going on here. The array `filter` is 3x3 but the subscripts you're using `i+k` and `j+l` are up to the size of the image. It looks like you've misplaced this addition:

```
total += intensity(image.getRGB(i+k,j+l)) * filter[k][l];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage), it's quite good for you.

Comment: I am learning image processing so I rather not rely on any library !